# Better replacement for a huge "if x==2 / if x==3 / if x==4" chain adding prefixes and suffixes?

Tags: python, if-statement

I am new to python. I have made a simple program that checks what the user input into the variable. According the the length of the string, my program will add words onto the front and back using an if statement...

```
if len(initialPass) == 2:
    finalPass = "@" + finalPass + "0010"
if len(initialPass) == 3:
    finalPass = "#" + finalPass + "0011"
if len(initialPass) == 4:
    finalPass = "$" + finalPass + "0100"
if len(initialPass) == 5:
    finalPass = "%" + finalPass + "0101"
if len(initialPass) == 6:
    finalPass = "^" + finalPass + "0010"
if len(initialPass) == 7:
    finalPass = "&" + finalPass + "0111"
if len(initialPass) == 8:
    finalPass = "*" + finalPass + "1000"
if len(initialPass) == 9:
    finalPass = "(" + finalPass + "1001"
if len(initialPass) == 10:
    finalPass = ")" + finalPass + "1010"
if len(initialPass) == 11:
    finalPass = ")!" + finalPass + "1011"
if len(initialPass) == 12:
    finalPass = ")@" + finalPass + "1100"
if len(initialPass) == 13:
    finalPass = ")#" + finalPass + "1101"
if len(initialPass) == 14:
    finalPass = ")$" + finalPass + "1110"
if len(initialPass) == 15:
    finalPass = ")%" + finalPass + "1111"
if len(initialPass) == 16:
    finalPass = ")^" + finalPass + "10000"
if len(initialPass) == 17:
    finalPass = ")&" + finalPass + "10001"
if len(initialPass) == 18:
    finalPass = ")*" + finalPass + "10010"
if len(initialPass) == 19:
    finalPass = ")(" + finalPass + "10011"
if len(initialPass) == 20:
    finalPass = "))" + finalPass + "10100"
```

Is there a better way to doing this?

Comment: Instead of branching like crazy, you should create a [lookup table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table), in this case as a list because the indices are rather dense, for the strings you need (think of a Python list as array of references, so accessing by index is O(1)).  Then just use `len(initialPass)` as index to retrieve items from that table.  In general, when the keys/indices are sparse, use a Python dictionary for the table instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

You want to use `len(initialPass)` for two things:

1) Get the first part of the final password, one of `"@"`, `"#"`, etc.

The easiest way to do this is to use a look-up table:

```
>>> extra = [' ', ' ', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', ')!', ')@', ')#', ')$', ')%', ')^', ')&', ')*', ')(', '))']
>>> extra[2]
'@'
>>> extra[5]
'%'
```

If you don't want to have the literal in the code like that, then you can generate it with this code instead:

```
>>> extra = list("  @#$%^&*()") + [")%s" % c for c in "!@#$%^&*()"]
```

2) Convert the initial pass to binary, padded with 0s, with at least 4 digits:

```
>>> "{0:04b}".format(2)
'0010'
>>> "{0:04b}".format(13)
'1101'
>>> "{0:04b}".format(23)
'10111'
```

Putting it together:

```
finalPass = extra[len(initialPass)] + finalPass + "{0:04b}".format(len(initialPass))
```

Comment: I'm sorry can you please break this down for me. I will use it as my solution, but I want to understand it too.

Comment: @GavinYouker: Yep, take a look!

Answer (score 0):

You can define a dictionary function for lookup for the prefix and suffix.  Separately handle for missing values

```
def look(i):
   return {
      2: ("@","0010"),
      3: ("#","0011"),
      ...
   }.get(i, ("PRE","SUF"))    # default values if not found
```

also, looks like your suffix is the binary representation of the length which can be formulated as well.

Comment: Check @Claudiu answer: You don't need a dictionary since there is a pattern with the numbers.